# Ajax function not showing JSON List of Dates (Mvc5)

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

In my MVC5 View, I'm calling a JSON function.
The JSON function returns an AvailableDates model, which has a Userld(string) and a LIST of DateTime objects defined.

My view is only able to read Userld but DateTime-objects appears as "undefined".
Can anyone see why I am not getting JSON DateTime LIST values in my view?

My JSON function:

```
public JsonResult GetFreeAppointmentDays()
{
 List<DateTime> avaliableBookingDays = new List<DateTime>();

 DateTime x1 = new DateTime(2017, 04, 11, 0, 0, 0);
 DateTime x2 = new DateTime(2017, 04, 12, 0, 0, 0);

 avaliableBookingDays.Add(x1.Date);
 avaliableBookingDays.Add(x2.Date);

 useravaliableDates AvaliableDates = new useravaliableDates()
 {
    UserIDs = "4,5,2,0,0,0,2",
    Avdata = avaliableBookingDays    
 };

 return Json(AvaliableDates, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Here is my View, with AJAX call:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="txtName" />
    <input type="button" id="btnGet" value="Get Current Time" />
    <div id="divshow"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#btnGet").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/GetFreeAppointmentDays",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                       
                        $('#divshow').append(data);
                        var items = '';
                        $.each(data.Avdata, function (i, item) {
                            var row = "UserIDs are: " + data.UserIDs + "  Date " + i + " -> " + item[i].Date + "<br/>"
                         
                            $('#divshow').append(row);
                        });
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

STRANGE: My JSON function return this

```
{"UserIDs":"4,5,2,0,0,0,2","Avdata":["\/Date(1491861600000)\/","\/Date(1491948000000)\/","\/Date(1492034400000)\/","\/Date(1492207200000)\/","\/Date(1492466400000)\/"]}
```

Comment: it is working for you ?  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting date in milliseconds format. 
Convert the C# date object to a string format and change `Avdata` property to a `List<String>`

```
avaliableBookingDays.Add(x1.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"));
avaliableBookingDays.Add(x2.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"));
```

Then convert it to a javascript date object:

```
var row = "UserIDs are: " + data.UserIDs + "  Date " + i + " -> " + new Date(item); + "<br/>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `function` which convert one date like `\/Date(1491861600000)\/` to real one. For this you can use `replace` method.

```
function parseDate(value){
   var newDate=new Date(parseInt(value.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/",""), 10));
   return newDate.getDate()+'/'(newDate.getMonth()+1)+'/'+newDate.getFullYear()
}
```

In your `each` method use `parseDate` function which I create above:

```
$.each(data.Avdata, function (i, item) {
    var row = "UserIDs are: " + data.UserIDs + "  Date " + i + " -> " + parseDate(item)+ "<br/>"
    $('#divshow').append(row);
});
```